# Mockito when()...then() NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mockito

productsInDatabse is a hashMap, output is enum, scanCode is from class which is tested

```
   public static boolean isInDataBase(int code) {
        return productsInDatabse.containsKey(code);
    }
```

and I've got a test:

```
@Test
public void testScanCodeForCodeNotFound() {

    Database db = Mockito.mock(Database.class);
    when(db.isInDataBase(444)).thenReturn(false);
    output = scanner.scanCode("444");
    assertTrue(output == ProductProcessing.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND);

}
```

But when()...then() returns with NPE. I saw examples when invoking was exactly like this. So my question is where is the bug, because I thought when()...then() works likes that.

Stacktrace:

```
Testcase: testScanCodeForCodeNotFound(iodevices.BarCodesScannerTest):   Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at database.Database.isInDataBase(Database.java:66)
    at iodevices.BarCodesScannerTest.testScanCodeForCodeNotFound(BarCodesScannerTest.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)


Test iodevices.BarCodesScannerTest FAILED
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Is the method `isInDataBase` final?

Comment: No, it is public static boolean isInDataBase(int code)

Comment: You're calling your static method from a non-static context. Also, you can't mock static methods.

Comment: Ok, so I can't mock static methods, that's sad... Is there workaround for this? Cause this method needs to be static,

Comment: Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock)

Comment: You are even using this static method wrong. You call it like an instance method: `db.isInDataBase(...)`. So even this test code is misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `static` from your `isInDataBase()` declaration.

See this if you can't remove the static: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock `static` methods with Mockito; you'll need [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) for that.