# Mockito : Testing boolean method with when()..then()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I found a similar question here: [Mockito when()...then() NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223126/mockito-when-then-nullpointerexception)
but in that question method to be tested was static.

I have a class with a boolean method to be tested. The test class gives NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION on the when()..then() line.

Thanks for your help.

**Class to be tested**

```
   public class FMBaseController implements FMHandler {

    private PlayerHandler player;

    public FMBaseController(PlayerHandler player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean boostValue(FamilyMember fm, int increase) {
        if (player.getResourceHandler().getServants() < increase)
            return false;
        return true;
```

**Tested class**

```
public class FMBaseControllerTest {

    //class to test
    private FMBaseController fmBase;

    //dependencies (these will be mocked)
    private FamilyMember fm;
    private PlayerHandler playerHandler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        fm = mock(FamilyMember.class);
        playerHandler = mock(PlayerHandler.class);

        fmBase = new FMBaseController(playerHandler);

    }

    @Test
    public void boostValueTest() {

        when(playerHandler.getResourceHandler().getServants()).thenReturn(3).thenReturn(5);

    //3 is less than 4 . assert you cannot boost
    Boolean bool1  = fmBase.boostValue(fm, 4);      
    assertFalse( bool1 );

    //5 is not less than 4 . assert you can boost
    Boolean bool2  = fmBase.boostValue(fm, 4);
    assertTrue( bool2 );
    }
}
```

**FAILURE TRACE**

```
FMBaseControllerTest
******.server.controller.FMBaseControllerTest
boostValueTest(******.server.controller.FMBaseControllerTest)
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at ******.server.controller.FMBaseControllerTest.boostValueTest(FMBaseControllerTest.java:44)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this into boostValueTest :

```
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = mock(resourceHandler.class);
when(playerHandler.getResourceHandler()).thenReturn(resourceHandler);
```

when you call :

`playerHandler.getResourceHandler().getServants()`

`playerHandler.getResourceHandler()` - returns null , as null is default result for all not mocked in mockito.

and your test method is green:

```
@Test
public void boostValueTest() {
    Servants servants = mock(Servants.class);
    when(playerHandler.getResourceHandler()).thenReturn(servants);

    when(playerHandler.getResourceHandler().getServants()).thenReturn(3).thenReturn(5);

    //3 is less than 4 . assert you cannot boost
    Boolean bool1  = fmBase.boostValue(fm, 4);
    assertFalse( bool1 );

    //5 is not less than 4 . assert you can boost
    Boolean bool2  = fmBase.boostValue(fm, 4);
    assertTrue( bool2 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. How would i test this else always in the same method ? With a verify?                                                                                                   else {
   player.getResourceHandler().payServants(increase);
   fm.setValue(fm.getValue() + increase);
   return true;
  }

Comment: It's helpful to know that payServants is a void method

Comment: yes. with verify(). do fo verify you also should add when . like doNothing().when(payServants(any() or value )..... verify(resourceHandler).payServants(any() or value)

Comment: I'll add this here if someone later comes:

Comment: doNothing().when(resourceHandler).payServants(Mockito.anyInt());
verify(resourceHandler).payServants(Mockito.anyInt());

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the default behaviour of Mockito, described in the [docs](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1):

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

Taking your call as an example `playerHandler.getResourceHandler().getServants()`, the `playerHandler` mock has no specified behaviour for the `getResourceHandler()` method, so it will return `null`, hence `null.getServants()` results in a NPE.

You can change this in at least the following 2 fashions:

- define a behaviour for your method as @sbjavateam suggested to return another mock `ResourceHandler`:

```java
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = mock(resourceHandler.class);
    when(playerHandler.getResourceHandler()).thenReturn(resourceHandler);
```

- configure Mockito to return [deep stubs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> Stubbing can be overridden: for example common stubbing can go to fixture setup but the test methods can override it. Please note that overridding stubbing is a potential code smell that points out too much stubbing

```java
    playerHandler = mock(PlayerHandler.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

or, if you're using annotations:

```java
   @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
   PlayerHandler playerHandler;
```

Nonetheless, while it's sometimes useful to do it, you should also take into account that:

> **WARNING**: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).
>
> Good quote I've seen one day on the web: **every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies**.
>
> Please note that this answer will return existing mocks that matches the stub. This behavior is ok with deep stubs and allows verification to work on the last mock of the chain.

Comment: Thank you! My classes are full of deep stubs, I guess it's too late to change it now

Answer (score 0):

By `PowerMockito` it could be done simpler.

But first of all I think it is better if your extract `playerHandler.getResourceHandler(). getServants()` to private method `getServants()`, because it doesn't look pretty good enough.

```
public class FMBaseController implements FMHandler {

    private PlayerHandler player;

    public FMBaseController(PlayerHandler player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean boostValue(FamilyMember fm, int increase) {
        return getServants() >= increase;
    }

    private int getServants() {
        return player.getResourceHandler().getServants();
    }
}
```

Then you may stub the this private method by `PowerMockito` by using `@RunWith` and `@PrepareForTest` class annotations.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyPrivate;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FMBaseController.class)
public class FMBaseControllerTest {

    private PlayerHandler playerHandler;
    private FamilyMember fm;
    private FMBaseController fmBaseController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        fm = mock(FamilyMember.class);
        playerHandler = mock(PlayerHandler.class);
        fmBaseController = spy(new FMBaseController(playerHandler));
    }

    @Test
    public void boostValue() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.doReturn(3, 4).when(fmBaseController, "getServants");

        assertFalse(fmBaseController.boostValue(fm, 4));
        assertTrue(fmBaseController.boostValue(fm, 4));

        verifyPrivate(fmBaseController, times(2)).invoke("getServants");
    }
}
```